# Connecting to Heroku Postgres Database with Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, heroku

I'm looking for the best way to connect to a Heroku Postgres database from an outside application.  The application is in asp.net. I am trying to use NpgSQL but am getting a certificate unknown error.  Has anyone done that?  Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO, what have you at least tried? Can you give us some starting code to help you?

Comment: Is PostgreSQL running SSL=on?

Answer (score 23):

I use this to "translate" the DATABASE_URL to a connection string

```
var databaseUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_URL");
var databaseUri = new Uri(databaseUrl);
var userInfo = databaseUri.UserInfo.Split(':');

var builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Host = databaseUri.Host,
    Port = databaseUri.Port,
    Username = userInfo[0],
    Password = userInfo[1],
    Database = databaseUri.LocalPath.TrimStart('/')
};

return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it worked for me! I just want to add, I needed to add to connect from my local to heroku server.
`SslMode = SslMode.Require,
TrustServerCertificate = true`

Answer (score 11):

I am using the following connection string to connect to Heroku Postgres Database:

```
string connString = "User ID=<user>;Password=<pass>;Host=<host>;Port=<port>;Database=<database>;Pooling=true;Use SSL Stream=True;SSL Mode=Require;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

where `<user>, <pass>, <host>, <port> and <database>` are values from heroku postgres app settings. Port is 5432 by default.

Then using [NpgSql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) I create instance of NpgsqlConnection:

```
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
```

Dafault sample: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html

Comment: For those reading in the future I highly recommend you obtain the database URI programmatically by using Heroku's Platform API - you can curl to get the database URI you'll have to pass in your authentication token as a header. @Set 's solution will work but is liable to break under certain circumstances.