# .net core - database url parser

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, heroku

I am deploying my .net core app on Heroku. Heroku provides the database url in the following format:

```
[database type]://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[database name]
```

EF expects the connection string to be in the format:

```
host=[host];user id=[username];password=[password];database=[database name];pooling=true;
```

Is there any parser available to convert, or I have to write the logic for the same myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple url parsing worked:

```
Uri url;
bool isUrl = Uri.TryCreate("postgres://1user:1password@dbserver.com:4568/testdb", UriKind.Absolute, out url);
if(isUrl) {
    Console.WriteLine("Host: "+url.Host);
    Console.WriteLine("Port: "+ url.Port);
    Console.WriteLine("Database: "+ url.LocalPath.Substring(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Username: "+ url.UserInfo.Split(':')[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Password: "+ url.UserInfo.Split(':')[1]);
    var connectionUrl = $"host={url.Host};username={url.UserInfo.Split(':')[0]};password={url.UserInfo.Split(':')[1]};database={url.LocalPath.Substring(1)};pooling=true;";
    Console.WriteLine(connectionUrl);
}
```

Comment: You could use `NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of string interpolation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53292619/1171276