# Using Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC Core, and PostgreSQL with Heroku

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework, heroku

I am attempting to use a PostgreSQL database managed by Heroku in an ASP.NET MVC app running on .NET core 2.0. I would like to be able to use the Entity Framework to easily read and write to the database. I am extremely new to all of these things except for ASP.NET, which is likely obvious, and having previously used a local SQLite server for this same purpose, I have almost no understanding of how PostgreSQL works with Heroku and the Entity Framework.

I have installed the [Npgsql extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) to the Entity Framework. I am stuck at the Entity Framework's connection string for this particular setup and how to use it with Heroku. Heroku supplies a `DATABASE_URL` variable (documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#designating-a-primary-database)), which is necessary to use because the [database connection credentials are subject to change](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) and Heroku automatically updates the variable when they change.

```
//This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to   
//the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    string connection = "???";
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
}
```

What value do I use for `connection` such that it will connect to the database through Heroku's URL independently of the current credentials? Additionally, how can I ensure that a table will be created in the database matching `MyDbContext`'s model?

My goal is simply to have a database accessible (read and write) from a deployed Heroku website. It would be nice if I could also access the database locally for development purposes, but my only requirement is that this work on the hosted website and that the database is managed by Heroku (I went with PostgreSQL, Kafka and Redis are also available through Heroku).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to "parse" the content of the `DATABASE_URL`environment variable provided by Heroku and use it to build the connection string in the format that the Npgsql expects.

For a quick and dirty solution, you can just follow this solution: [.net core - database url parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916910/1439862).

For my project I decided to go a little further and created a class for that, based in the other connection string builders (for MS SQL, Mongo and etc):

```
public enum SslMode
{
    Require, 
    Disable,
    Prefer
}

public class PostgreSqlConnectionStringBuilder : DbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    private string _database;
    private string _host;
    private string _password;
    private bool _pooling;
    private int _port;
    private string _username;
    private bool _trustServerCertificate;
    private SslMode _sslMode;

    public PostgreSqlConnectionStringBuilder(string uriString)
    {
        ParseUri(uriString);
    }

    public string Database
    {
        get => _database;
        set
        {
            base["database"] = value;
            _database = value;
        }
    }

    public string Host
    {
        get => _host;
        set
        {
            base["host"] = value;
            _host = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set
        {
            base["password"] = value;
            _password = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Pooling
    {
        get => _pooling;
        set
        {
            base["pooling"] = value;
            _pooling = value;
        }
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get => _port;
        set
        {
            base["port"] = value;
            _port = value;
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get => _username;
        set
        {
            base["username"] = value;
            _username = value;
        }
    }

    public bool TrustServerCertificate
    {
        get => _trustServerCertificate;
        set
        {
            base["trust server certificate"] = value;
            _trustServerCertificate= value;
        }
    }

    public SslMode SslMode
    {
        get => _sslMode;
        set
        {
            base["ssl mode"] = value.ToString();
            _sslMode = value;
        }
    }

    public override object this[string keyword]
    {
        get
        {
            if (keyword == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyword));
            return base[keyword.ToLower()];
        }
        set
        {
            if (keyword == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyword));

            switch (keyword.ToLower())
            {
                case "host":
                    Host = (string) value;
                    break;

                case "port":
                    Port = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "database":
                    Database = (string) value;
                    break;

                case "username":
                    Username = (string) value;
                    break;

                case "password":
                    Password = (string) value;
                    break;

                case "pooling":
                    Pooling = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                    break;

                case "trust server certificate":
                    TrustServerCertificate = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                    break;

                case "sslmode":
                    SslMode = (SslMode) value;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid keyword '{0}'.", keyword));
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool ContainsKey(string keyword)
    {
        return base.ContainsKey(keyword.ToLower());
    }

    private void ParseUri(string uriString)
    {
        var isUri = Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri);

        if (!isUri) throw new FormatException(string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid URI.", uriString));

        Host = uri.Host;
        Port = uri.Port;
        Database = uri.LocalPath.Substring(1);
        Username = uri.UserInfo.Split(':')[0];
        Password = uri.UserInfo.Split(':')[1];
    }
}
```

And then, in my `Startup.cs`, in the `Configuration` method, I have:

```
var builder = new PostgreSqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration["DATABASE_URL"])
{
    Pooling = true,
    TrustServerCertificate = true,
    SslMode = SslMode.Require
};

services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<TTRDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.ConnectionString));
```

If you are accessing your DB from outside Heroku network (e.g. your local environment), you need to add the `SSL Mode` and `Trust Server Certificate`.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot! I also didn't realize I had to call `services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()`.